# Javascript code runs fine... almost all the time

Tags: javascript

I have come across a problem that I cannot seem to resolve. Please take a look at the code below:

```
<script>
    function createFunctions() {
        var first = ["", "", ""];
        var second = ["", "", ""];
        var func = ["", ""];
        var sign = ["", ""];
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            first[i] = (Math.round(Math.random() * 9) + 1);
            second[i] = (Math.round(Math.random() * 9) + 1);
            sign[i] = (Math.round(Math.random()));
            if (sign[i] == "1") {
                sign[i] = '+';
            } else {
                sign[i] = '-';
            }
            if (first < 2) {
                func[i] = 'f(x) = x ' + sign[i] + ' ' + second[i] + '<p>';
            } else {
                func[i] = 'f(x) = ' + first[i] + 'x ' + sign[i] + ' ' + second[i] + '<br>';
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            document.getElementById("createFunctions").innerHTML += 'Function ' + [i + 1] + ': ' + func[i];
        }
        //whichFunction=
        findAnswers(first, second, sign);
    }

    function findAnswers(first, second, sign, rand) {
        var num = ["", "", ""];
        rand = (Math.round(Math.random() * 1));
        document.getElementById("findAnswers").innerHTML = 'Which <b>one (or more)</b> of these functions holds true, when plugged in with the following <b>values of x</b>? (' + [rand + 1] + ')<br>';
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            num[i] = (Math.round(Math.random() * 9));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ans = 0;
            if (sign[rand] == "+") {
                ans = [first[rand] * num[i]] + second[rand];
            } else {
                ans = [first[rand] * num[i]] - second[rand];
            }
            document.getElementById("findAnswers").innerHTML += [i + 1] + '. You put in a ' + num[i] + ': ' + ans + '<br>';
        }
    }
</script>

<BODY onload=createFunctions()>
    <b>A Machine Called Effex</b>
    <p><input type="button" value="New Examples" onclick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh"></p>
    <p id="createFunctions"></p>
    <p id="findAnswers"></p>
```

Everything works great. Except occasionally, when calculating the function, the code multiplies by x, and then simply concatenates the second value onto the first, instead of adding (or subtracting).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `first[i] < 2` on line 15?

Comment: Try changing the outer most square brackets to parenthesis in `[first[rand]*num[i]] + second[rand]` on line 36 & 38 and also cast the operands to int using parseInt on these lines

Comment: changed the arrays from `var array = ["", "", ""]` to `var array=[]` as it just creates an empty array and `i` does the rest in the for loops. have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/zzx5w79a/ maybe you want to include this link to your question. I couldn't find the "occasionally .., the code multiplies.."

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thank you. Could you please give me a briefer on why () were better there instead of []?

Comment: As a follow-up, how terrible is this code? I personally wouldn't call it elegant, but does is it decently written?

Comment: The use of square brackets as parens is terrible indeed, as it is turning single values into arrays, but clear that up and it might not be too bad.  But I do question the use of rounding random times nine.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should change `[first[rand]*num[i]]` to `(first[rand]*num[i])`.
The [] bracket is instantiating an array with only one value (the product of your multiplication) and then you're 'adding' the array to a number, which forces the engine to cast the array to a string and concatenate the string with the number you're 'adding'.

To illustrate, consider the code below. It also instantiates an array but casts it to a number using the [unary + operator](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/). This will result in a numerical value and not an array, so your code will work as expected.

```
+[first[rand]*num[i]]
```

To further illustrate what's happening, consider the code below. It too instantiates a single-element array, but by appending it with [0], we specify the (numerical) value of that element and so the engine is not forced to cast the array to a string when you use the + operator.

```
[first[rand]*num[i]][0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. Don't forget to select the appropriate answers to resolved questions.